# How to block a button in qml in a cpp file?

Tags: qt, c++11, qml

I want to block a button in a qml file when my function in cpp is called.

How can I do this?

Comment: by blocking you mean disabling it right?

Comment: yes, like I can't click in this button anymore.

Comment: ok, then set the property enable.... to false... see my answer as a guide to it...

Comment: You can consider to add a State to your qml, and disable the button matching a particular state. Then in your cpp is enough to change the state of the object. This should be a cleanest approach rather then controlling gui from logic

Answer (score 1):

you have a button and lets say you are using qml and c++ you can interact between them as in de [doc](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) explained

```
then you can invoke the `setProperty` method 

// Using QQmlComponent
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlComponent component(&engine,
        QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
QObject *object = component.create();
object->setProperty("width", 500);
...
delete object;
```

Comment: How can I do this without change the main or create a new object?

Answer (score 0):

In your c++ function you can emit signal of class, which should be visible in QML too:

```
void yourFunction() {
    emit yourClassInstance.nameOfSignal;
}
```

You can register your class in QML:

```
engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty(<Name of your class in qml>, <reference to instance of your class>);
```

After that you can use Connection to connect signal from your c++ class to js function like that:

```
Connection {
   target: <Name of your class in qml>

   onNameOfSignal: {
       // Disable button here
   }
}
```